# What are the pros and cons of using an HTML parsing package like html-react-parser vs dangerouslySetInnerHtml in React

Tags: reactjs, html-parsing, dangerouslysetinnerhtml, html-react-parser

We have a database containing HTML code and we are displaying that on a web page using React, but it needs to be parsed.

I initially used [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) but after a code review was asked to use [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) instead because it doesn't have any dependencies.

I wasn't able to articulate any advantages of using html-react-parser other than it doesn't use dangerouslySetInnerHtml, but is that an advantage and if so why? Does it somehow avoid the dangers or are they just hidden?

Many thanks,

Katie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've recently been studying this issue for a Headless CMS project I'm working on.  From what I understand:

`dangerouslySetInnerHtml` creates DOM elements outside of `ReactDOM.Render()` method, so it's not dynamically maintained by the React library. This  basically defeats the purpose of using React in the first place (displaying and maintaining virtual DOM).

More concerning, though, is that it's vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks, which is where it gets its name.  These are a very common form of attack on the web. You can read about that here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

If you want the app to be less prone to attacks, you'll have to use a sanitization library like `DOMPurify` for `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`, so you're likely to have another dependency either way.  Once you compile the app for production (`npm build`) the minimization process makes the codebase extremely compact, and you can do some optimization beforehand with techniques like code-splitting, which makes each section of your page load only if requested, instead of all at once: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

I wouldn't worry too much about a few dependencies, personally - they're a fact of life on the modern web. I've been leaning towards using `html-react-parser`, but I caveat that by saying I have not investigated whether it reduces XSS vulnerability.  However, even if both are vulnerable to XSS attacks, at least `html-react-parser` introduces the elements through `ReactDOM.render()` so they don't make the DOM all catty-wompus - that sounds like a recipe for disaster down the road.

Comment: I realise you answered this many months ago, but I've only just spotted your reply. Thank you very much  - I appreciate your thorough answer!

Comment: Absolutely. Actually, I'm glad you reminded me of it because I am currently working on a project that uses it again, and I had forgotten about this answer, so it worked out great.

Comment: What if the HTML content is my own, will it still be prone to attack if I use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`.

Comment: It still has the same vulnerability because someone can modify what you call your HTML wherever it is stored. There's always the risk of unauthorized access to your database or wherever you are storing your raw HTML.